# Using ThrottleTime with value 60000 is throwing a warning, should this be of concern?

Tags: react-native, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using an epic that runs every 60 seconds.  With that value I'm getting a warning:

`Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
(Saw setInterval with duration 600000ms)`

Will this be a problem for me and if so, do you have a suggested alternative?

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproduction stackblitz ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun what would be useful?  I don't have the time to create a whole new app ATM.  The epic uses `.throttleTime(600000)...`